# How to reduce polygon count

Tags: objects, interface, edit-mode, import, faces

I want to reduce the polygon count from a model of around 50,000 faces to exactly 1,000 faces. Give me the settings and numbers okay?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=reduce+polygon

Answer (score 1):

It is *impossible* to exactly reduce the amount of faces of an object, but there are tricks to doing so:

1) Use the **decimate** modifier, and adjust the settings while watching the faces-count and the quality of the object.
Here's how this works: Go to the modifiers tab, and select *decimate*. Then set this modifier to un-subdivide. The modifier will show the amount of faces in the object at the bottom. Set the *iterations* amount, (a couple should do fine), and watch the quality of the object and the amount of faces.

2) Another thing to do: *Limited Dissolve* in edit mode. This won't let you specify the face-count, but you can adjust it so that you get a lower-poly result.
Do this by selecting the object, going to edit mode, and selecting **mesh > cleanup > limited dissolve**. Adjust the angle factor, and watch the faces.

3) *Nobody* wants to do this, but go to edit mode, select certain faces and press <kbd>F</kbd> on the computer keyboard. Manually combine the faces until you have exactly 1000 faces (if you want), or as many as needed.

<kbd>I hope these tips help you, and/or answer your question!</kbd>